# Pyramid Script using PasteDeploy Pipeline not working

Tags: python, configuration, pyramid, paster

Hello here's my new trouble...
i'm using pyramid and i have created a script to fill my db with initial data

I have a PasteDeploy configuration file (say *development.ini*) with this syntax

```
###
# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html
###

[app:shop_eshop]
use = egg:shop_eshop

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_debugtoolbar
    pyramid_tm

sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://eshop_db_user:testtest@localhost:5432/eshop_db

jinja2.directories = eshop:templates

ziggurat_foundations.model_locations.User = auth.models:User

# SESSION_BEAKER
session.type = file
session.data_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/data
session.lock_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/lock
session.key = s_key
session.secret = ...FBIRootAccessPW...
session.cookie_on_exception = true


[filter:fanstatic]
use = egg:fanstatic#fanstatic
recompute_hashes = false
versioning = true
bottom = True

publisher_signature = assets
compile = true
#in development
debug = true

[pipeline:main]
pipeline = fanstatic eshop

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, shop_eshop, sqlalchemy

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_shop_eshop]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = shop_eshop

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

My script contains this piece of code that generates the error..

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        usage(argv)
    config_uri = argv[1]
    options = parse_vars(argv[2:])

    setup_logging(config_uri)

    settings = get_appsettings(config_uri, options=options)
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)

    with transaction.manager:
        create_groups()
        create_users()
```

The error is thrown by this line

```
engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
```

If i remove the pipeline everything works correctly, i can't find a way to read the pipeline.

Here's my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/srv/michael/e_shop/env/bin/fill_e_shop_db", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('e_shop==0.0', 'console_scripts', 'fill_e_shop_db')()
File "/srv/michael/e_shop/e_shop/e_shop/scripts/filldb.py", line 98, in main
engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 350, in engine_from_config
KeyError: 'url'
```

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: can you include the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes.. i forgot to mention the error .. sorry..

Comment: looks like the easiest fix would be to put sqlalchemy.url in the global section of your ini but the problem is that the variable settings is not what you are probably expecting. print settings and see whats in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_appsettings()` is loading the settings for the `main` section of your ini file, unless otherwise specified. There are obviously no settings in that section. If you want to load the settings for a specific section then just specify that using the `#`. For example you should be able to run your program right now and get the result you want:

```
myprog development.ini#shop_eshop
```